# Safe login inside a web page(java servlet)

Tags: servlets, authentication

I create a web page which takes user naame and if it is true, it shows some information(using servlet)   otherwise it return nothing 
I have a question that  is this  standard approach or safe.
I know that I should use a database but simplifying code  I did not use and session time out doesn't matter here I  will handle it.
Is this method safe.
Thanks

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName =request.getParameter("uname");
    String passWord =request.getParameter("pass");
    if(!userName.equals("admin"))
        return;
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet fservlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("<h3>Hi " +userName+ "</h3>");

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");


    }
}
```

Comment: where are you checking whether the password and username are matching...?

Comment: I want to know that this way is correct or not.It is demo the
username & password matching is not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really think it is a good way to follow. Because you are sending the username and password on the request object.. so if somebody track your request, they can easily see your credentials which is a security threat. If you are concern on such requirements on your question, I would like to suggest you to use some key encryption mechanism to first encrypt it on client side before passing it to server side.

example:
http://www.jcryption.org/
http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

hope this will provide you a thought !!